# Как удалить Item из ListBox.ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

Казалось бы, все просто.

```
MyCollection.Remove(theListBoxItem);
```

А как быть, если у меня нет этого самого MyCollection? Например, если это стиль для ListBox и возможность удаления я задаю в нем. ListBox.Items.Remove() тоже не помогает. Исключение говорит, что так делать нельзя, когда мой лист заполняется через биндинг. Как быть?

**UPD:**
Сумел решить так

```
lb.ItemsSource.GetType().GetMethod("Remove").Invoke(lb.ItemsSource, new object[] { el });
```

Но мне не хочется в данном случае связываться с рефлексиями. Я вообще пытаюсь их избегать. Есть ли другое решение?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34762/discussion-on-question-by-irumba---item--listbox-itemssource).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ListBox привязан к коллекции, и есть ссылка на ListBoxItem, то чтобы получить соответствующий элемент коллекции надо вызвать метод ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer.
Элемент можно удалить из коллекции через метод IList.Remove

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Width="300" Height="300">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseUp="ListBox_MouseUp">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    class Data {
        public int Prop { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Window1 : Window {
        public Window1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ObservableCollection<Data>() {
                new Data { Prop = 1 },
                new Data { Prop = 2 }
            };
        }
        private void ListBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            var lb = (System.Windows.Controls.ListBox) sender;
            var li = FindAncestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
            var o = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(li);
            (lb.ItemsSource as IList).Remove(o);
        }
        static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject {
            do {
                if (current is T) return (T)current;
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            }
            while (current != null);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```